# How to find average in .txt file that contains letters and numbers

Tags: python, file, average

I have made a program that should ask the user if they want the average of the contents in the file. There has three files the user can choose from.My program has other options like alphabetically last result and highest to lowest. When I add the average to the script it will say the following:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'g 2\n'
```

I assume that this is because the str is attached in the file with the result.
My code:

```
elif viewhours==('hours a ave'): #If the users input is equal to hours a ave then the script will process the average.
    averageHours=[]#This is an empty list.
with open('hours a.txt') as f: #Opens the file, but manipulates it appending the contents inside.
   for line in f: #This part helps to analyse the lines in the file and wraps the code.
       if line.strip(): #This skips a blank line in the file and goes to another line.
          averageHours.append(int(line.strip()))
          #This outputs the average to the screen by appending it
```

How would I get the numbers/results from the file ignoring the letters inside the file to get the outputted average?

The file with contents:

```
bill 4
```

Comment: Do you have example files?

Comment: @ergonaut i edited the question

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service, and we aren't here to help you cheat on your GCSE coursework. Please read [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe is this a Gcse question?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is space delimited, a possible solution is:

```
import csv

data=[]

with open('data.csv', mode='r') as file:
    newfile = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ' ')
    for line in newfile:
        data.append(line[1])
```

The input file you've given:

```
clive 10
bill 4
```

Now `data` is a list containing the numbers from that file:

```
10
4
```

Comment: avoid naming the variable `list`, otherwise it will shadow the built-in `list` name

Comment: Furthermore, given the OP wants the numbers only, why not appending those only?